# if/then loop using `cat`

Tags: shell-script

teams.txt:

```
Bills
Jets
Dolphin
Patriots
```

.

```
for team in `cat teams.txt`
do
    if ["$team" == "Bills"]
    then
        echo "$team hired Rex Ryan as coach"
    fi
    echo "$team Nation"
done
```

I keep getting the error:

```
teams.sh: line 5: [Bills: command not found
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong with my code.

Answer (score 5):

You are missing space around [ and ]. It should looks like this:

```
for team in `cat teams.txt`
do
    if [ "$team" == "Bills" ]
    then
        echo "$team hired Rex Ryan as coach"
    fi
    echo "$team Nation"
done
```